# Including controller in php code in view file

Tags: php, autoload, include-path

I'm working on a PHP project using *MVC architecture*. In my project file I have the `index.php` file along with the `model` folder, `controller` folder and `view`* folder.

In my index file I've written this code:

```
`<?php
  include("./controller/controllerUser.php");
  $ocont = new controllerUser();
  if (isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $ocont->{$_GET['action']}();
  } 
?>`
```

The *controllerUser* (located inside the **controller folder**) redirect the site to my *ViewLogin* file (located inside the **view folder**), till here it's all working fine.

The problem is when I click on the sign up button on my `viewLogin` file, it redirects me to the `ViewSignup` file (located inside the `view` folder), but I get those errors:

```
Warning: include(..\Model\controllerUser.php) [function.include]: failed to    open stream: No such file or directory in    D:\wamp\www\projetphp\view\ViewSignup.php on line 45
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '.\controller\controllerUser.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\projetphp\view\viewSignup.php on line 45
Fatal error: Class 'controllerUser' not found in D:\wamp\www\projetphp\view\ViewSignIn.php on line 51
```

I think that the problem is with the inclusion of the `controllerUser` file in the PHP code in the `ViewSignup` page.
This is my code:

```
include  ('.\controller\controllerUser.php');
$ocontuser = new  controllerUser(); 
$ocontuser->Actions2_SignIn();
```

I tried this too, but got more errors:

```
include  ('..\controller\controllerUser.php');
$ocontuser = new  controllerUser(); 
$ocontuser->Actions2_SignIn();
```

*What should I do to fix this error?*

Answer (score 0):

One fix is to define an application root folder.  Example

APP_ROOT = 'c:\www';

or in this case:

APP_ROOT = 'D:\wamp\www\projetphp';

Then each file includes files like this:

include (APP_ROOT . '\controller\controllerUser.php');

It's a good idea to create a "config.php" and define 'APP_ROOT' in the config file.  Then each file includes the "config.php" at the top ensuring that APP_ROOT is always defined the same way in each and every file where config.php is included.  It is also easy to update APP_ROOT if the root changes.  I hope this helps.